# Как правильно скрыть label с помощью атрибута for?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть вот такой label:

```
<label class="adm-designed-checkbox-label" for="UF_SKILL1" title=""></label>
```

Пытаюсь скрыть его с помощью jquery таким образом:

```
$("label[for='UF_SKILL1']").css('display', 'none');
```

Подскажите что не правильно?

```js
$("label[for='UF_SKILL1']").css('display', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="adm-designed-checkbox-label" for="UF_SKILL1" title=""></label>
```

Comment: судя по сниппету твой код работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неправильно то, что Вы зачем-то делаете это с помощью jQuery. Но вообще Ваш код прекрасно работает (я добавил timeout для наглядности):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
   $("label[for='UF_SKILL1']").css('display', 'none');
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="adm-designed-checkbox-label" for="UF_SKILL1" title="">Лейбл</label>
```

Comment: А есть другие способы? просто `id` к `label`  я не могу добавить. Надо как то через `for`...

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov, не очень понимаю - а где здесь к label добавлен id? Здесь через for и работает. Или что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: "Неправильно то, что Вы зачем-то делаете это с помощью jQuery."

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov, а, ну я имел в виду, что это на css делается обычно. Хотя, конечно, смотря какая задача стоит...

Comment: спасибо тебе большое!!

Comment: @Evgeny, рад помочь :)